# Increase max open files for Ubuntu/Upstart (initctl)

Tags: ubuntu, file-descriptor, upstart

This is on an Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS server.

I've added the following to /etc/security/limits.conf (my Golang processes run as root):

```
*      hard   nofile   50000
*      soft   nofile   50000
root   hard   nofile   50000
root   soft   nofile   50000
```

I've added the following to /etc/pam.d/common-session

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

I've added the following to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
fs.file-max = 50000
```

Yet when I cat /proc/{PID}/limits, I get:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
```

This happens **only when I start the process from Upstart via sudo initctl start service_name**. If I start the process myself, it acknowledges my settings.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This needs to be added to your Upstart script for it to work:

```
limit nofile 50000 50000
```

> "It's by design that upstart does not look at
>   /etc/security/limits.conf for system jobs. PAM settings are only
>   applied to user sessions, not to system services." from
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/938669

Sources:

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/5323

http://bryanmarty.com/blog/2012/02/10/setting-nofile-limit-upstart/