# Too many open files raised by supervisord?

Tags: linux, supervisord

I use `wrk` to test web API service managed by supervisor on `ubuntu 16.04`. have error "too many open files", but i have set system config

```
/etc/security/limits.conf
*           soft    nofile  65535
*           hard    nofile  65535
```

still have error "too many open files"

I found supervisord is belongs to `root` and `cat /proc/PID/limits`

```
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
```

so, add root limit settings to `limits.conf` like below

```
root        soft    nofile  65535
root        hard    nofile  65535
```

after restart supervisord it's effected (cat `/proc/PID/limits`, got 65535)
but supervisord exit soon after, and auto start with limits 1024.

```
Jul 12 18:55:53 adhost supervisord[10866]: Error: Another program is already listening on a port that one of our HTTP servers is configured to use.  Shut this program down first before starting supervisord.
Jul 12 18:55:53 adhost supervisord[10866]: For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
Jul 12 18:55:53 adhost systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jul 12 18:55:53 adhost supervisorctl[10871]: Shut down
```

reference: [ubuntu - too many open files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901518/ubuntu-too-many-open-files)

Comment: The doesn't look like it's related to open file limits? It loos like the service is already running?

Comment: thanks for your kindness @RamanSailopal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by `sudo supervisorctl shutdown` should't kill P directly